# call 'requestWindowFeature' from another Class

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-context

I am trying to access `requestWindowFeature()` from another Class called `MyFunctions`

here is my MyFunctions Class

```
public class MyFunctions {

    Context context;

    public MyFunctions(Context c)
    {
        c = context;
    }

    public void hideBars(Context context)
    {
        //HIDING TOP TITLE TAB
        context.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //HIDING TOP TOOL BAR
        context.getWindow().setFlags(
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    }

}
```

but it showing an error like this

[image]

What should i do to access `requestWindowFeature()` and `getWindow()` from another class ?

Best answer will be apreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getWindow()` and `requestWindowFeature()` are methods of `Activity` not `Context`.

Pass a reference of the `Activity` to your class / method.

```
public void hideBars(Activity activity)
{
    //HIDING TOP TITLE TAB
    activity.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //HIDING TOP TOOL BAR
    activity.getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

}
```